# C linkage and c++ headers

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, linkage

I want to use some c++ classes in shared library with C linkage. And i got following problems.

If

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
 void f(){}
}
```

Compiles and links succesfully, but f() could not be found in resulting library.

If

```
extern "C"
{
#include <iostream>
 void f(){}
}
```

I got many compiler errors (just dont know how to correctly translate them in english, something about template with C linkage) on every occurence of C++ keyword "template" in iostream and included headers.

What should be done?

Answer (score 4):

The first variant is correct. Only stuff that even exists in C can be declared in a `extern "C"` block, and templates and classes certainly don't belong in that category. You only have to make sure, that your function is also declared as `extern "C"` in the header if you are using a C++-compiler. This is often achieved by writing

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// C++ declarations (for example classes or functions that have C++ objects
//                   as parameters)

extern "C"
{
#endif

// C declarations (for example your function f)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

in the header.

Answer (score 2):

The first is correct; system headers (and most other headers as well)
can only be included at global scope, outside any namespaces, classes,
functions or linkage specification blocks.  There are likely things in
`<iostream>` that wouldn't be legal in an `extern "C"`, and even if
there weren't, the name mangling for `extern "C"` is almost certainly
different from that of C++, and the library itself was surely compiled
as `extern "C++"`.

How did you define `f`?  This could be a similar problem: if the source
file compiles it as an `extern "C++"` function, then the name will be
mangled differently than it was in the client files which compiled it as 
an `extern "C"` function.

The general policy here is to handle the headers and the function
definitions/declarations in the same way you normally do, except that
you ensure that the header can be included in both C and C++ sources,
e.g.:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void f();
//  Other `extern "C"` functions...
#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then include this header in all files where the function `f()` is used,
and in the file where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use [__declspec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to export functions, classes, etc...
Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d(v=vs.80).aspx

And this one is very good: http://www.flounder.com/ultimateheaderfile.htm

Comment: This is not portable, the OP didn't say what compiler he uses.

Comment: Yes, forgot to say. I use gcc 4.6.1 and Linux.

Comment: You do not have to use declspec (even on Windows), and by using extern "C" it is cross-compatible with other C++ compilers as well as possibly C code itself.

If this is being built on Windows as the platform you would then use the .def file to declare the symbol in the export table.